# Turns Windows features on or off hangs searching for required files

Tags: windows-10, iis

We've tried twice to turn on `Static Content`.

```
Turn Windows features on or off
    Internet Information Services
        World Wide Web Services
            Common HTTP Features
                Static Content
```

Both times, the Windows Features dialog hangs for 10+ minutes while Searching for required files.

[image: Searching for required files hangs]

How can we enable Static Content?

Comment: Download Windows ISO, mount the ISO with DISM, then enable the feature and use the ISO as the source

Comment: @Ramhound How come such a workaround is necessary? How, if it all, can we fix the underlying problem?

Comment: What work around?  In order to install the feature you must have the required files. It’s only a suggestion anyways

Comment: In the past, Enabling Static Content has worked without downloading the Windows ISO. That is why I am considering it to be a workaround.